# adding Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1 prerequisite to InstallShield 2013

Tags: .net, installshield, prerequisites

I was wondering if someone could explain the steps needed to add MS Framework 4.5.1 as a prerequisite to an `installshield` `Basic MSI Project` I am creating.

We have `installshield 2013` which only has `4.5` out of the box.  I know that version 2014 has added this framework as an option out of the box.

I would like to know how you can add it manually, so that the person installing our MSI can have the option to include (or point to Microsoft download location) it since the application that is being installed will need that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing as finally upgrading.   I realize this is not a direct solution to how to add it to 2013 but it was determined that 2013 was fairly old in terms of releases, so we upgraded.   After doing that, we were able to add the framework prereq. in easily.